# WordNetLemmatizer funciona com palavras em português?

Tags: python, inteligência-artificial, chatbot, nltk

Estou criando meu primeiro ChatBot com Natural Language e gostaria de saber se ao importar para o Python a biblioteca:

`from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer`

O lemmatizer funciona também para palavras em português?

Exemplo:

Em inglês Work --> Works, Worked, Working...

Em português ficaria algo como "Trabalhos", "Trabalhando", "Trabalhei" ?

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://gist.github.com/hugoncosta/2fa5684c43724584eb0ae8657d28f80a) ajuda. É capaz de vc precisar do [lemmatization-pt.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michmech/lemmatization-lists/master/lemmatization-pt.txt)

Comment: Não cheguei a testar ainda, mas estou tendo o mesmo problema, até agora as soluções mais viáveis encontrei aqui: https://github.com/fmaruki/Nltk-Tagger-Portuguese https://streamhacker.com/2008/11/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-1/

Comment: A biblioteca Spacy é uma ótima alternativa para isso: https://spacy.io/models/pt